# How to get the document ids of all documents accessible by a user in google drive?

Tags: google-api, google-drive-api

I tried using the Google Document List API "https://docs.google.com/feeds/default/private/full?max-results=100&showfolders=true" for fetching list of all files and documents accessible to a user.

But got the Error as - "Invalid request URI".

Please can anyone explain what is it that I am missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try appending ?v=3 at the end or alternatively you can add an HTTP header GData-Version: 3 That should fix it.

This is because this API endpoint only works with the latest version of the Document List API and, by default the API uses v1. So you get the same error as you you were using ?v=1